# How can I calculate number of purchases without using GROUP BY?

Tags: sql

I'm working on a table which looks like this:

```
PURCHASE

PurchaseNo
ReceiptNo
```

The first three digits in 'Receiptno' represents the receipt book that the receipt is from. How can I write a query to count the number of purchases where at least 10 other purchases have come from the same receipt book?

My first approach was to use GROUP BY on the receipt book digits, but how can I do it **without** grouping the digits (I can still use GROUP BY elsewhere)?

This would've been my attempt if I grouped by receipt book:

```
SELECT SUM(total)
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(PURCHASENO) AS total, SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 1,3)
FROM PURCHASE
GROUP BY SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO,1,3)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use a `GROUP BY` in your subquery?

Comment: @Nick because I'm working through a question sheet and the next question requires me to create an index on the ReceiptNo field. If I group by the three digits, it will make the index ineffective.

Comment: You can create an index on the first 3 characters of `RECEIPTNO`. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html#create-index-column-prefixes)

Comment: If you care about indexes, why not have a separate column called receipt book?

Comment: @Nick Yes, but the question wants me to solve the problem without an index and then the next question would make me create an index. The purpose of that is just to demonstrate that indexes could make queries faster. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: That's not incompatible with using a `GROUP BY` on the three digits in this question; you can then create an index on those three digits for the next question.

Comment: @Nick our lecturer had personally told us not to use a `GROUP BY` on the three digits in the question unfortunately. Instead, she suggested looking into self joins, but I have no idea how to apply them to that problem.

Comment: @YxngHxy . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use window functions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT PURCHASENO AS total,
             SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 1, 3) as receipt_book
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTR(RECEIPTNO, 1, 3)) as receipt_book
      FROM PURCHASE
     ) p
HAVING receipt_book >= 11;
```

You can also use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from purchase p
where (select count(*)
       from purchase p2
       where substr(p2.receiptno, 1, 3) = substr(p.receiptno, 1, 3)
      ) >= 11;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(total) from (
select distinct count(PURCHASENO) over(partition by substr(ReceiptNo,1,3)) as total from PURCHASE
) where total>10
```